# Transport as a noun in American English

Tags: word-choice, difference, american-english, nouns

“Sam took a transport to mother’s house”.

For a matter of style I want to use the word transport or transportation as a synonym of vehicle, but for American readers. I read that in AE transport is never a noun except for a few cases (which I don’t know). Transportation to me sounds like a robust kind of conveyance of people or things (for instance, transport for a taxi, but transportation for the whole taxi system of a given place). I want to know if the phrase above sounds OK to AE speakers when meaning that Sam went to his mother’s by car, taxi or even a bus – public or private.

Comment: Its not okay for British English speakers. You can't use "transport" in that way.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of written instances of *(someone) [**took transport to**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22took%20transport%20to%22) (some destination)*, where it's important to note there's ***no article***. If you look at the dates in that link, you'll see most of them are quite old.

Also note that in such contexts, ***transport*** is effectively equivalent to ***transportation***. It's more of an abstract than a concrete noun - referring to *a **means** of travel*, rather than a specific "conveyance" (a ***physical thing*** in which passengers / cargo are transported).

You won't see the usage ***a transport*** (*with* an article) very often at all. It's sometimes used (mainly in military or technological contexts) where *the fact of things/people being transported* is more relevant than the *actual thing* they're transported in/by.

---

OP's example context *(Sam took a transport to the house)* is completely non-idiomatic, and always was. *Without* the article, it's "just about" valid, but it sounds like something out of a Dickens (Victorian) novel.

Note that it wouldn't be unusual to say *Sam **arranged** transport to the house* even today, but that wouldn't necessarily mean that he actually made the journey at the time (perhaps he made travel arrangements for someone else, or for his own *future* journey).

To sum up, ***Sam took transport to the house*** is technically valid (with the sense of ***made use of a transportation service / type of transport***), but you *can't* use ***a transport*** in such contexts as a generic reference to *an individual conveyance / vehicle / vessel used to transport something*.