# Means of transport for people?

Tags: translation

The Dutch goverment is introducing a new reporting requirement in 2024 for companies with 100 employees or more:

[Rapportageverplichting werkgebonden personenmobiliteit](https://www.rvo.nl/onderwerpen/rapportage-wpm)
[Reporting obligation work-related mobility of persons](https://english.rvo.nl/information/reporting-obligation-work-related-mobility-persons)

They must report how their employees travel in order to calculate total CO2 emissions.

For this they need to register the 'vervoermiddel' (fuel car, electric car, bike, ...) used by employees.

I'm struggling with the translation of 'vervoermiddel' here. 'Means of transport' to me sounds like moving goods (or animals), not people.
Is 'means of transport' good (enough) or is there a better translation for 'vervoermiddel'?

Somewhat related:
[What do cars do with their passengers?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/255203/what-do-cars-do-with-their-passengers)
[Transport as a noun in American English](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/228428/transport-as-a-noun-in-american-english/228434#228434)

Comment: *Means of transport* is fine for people. Another term is "transportation mode(s)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Transport** can certainly be used with reference to people. **Public transport** is the term for travel in vehicles that are not privately owned. **Transport for London** is the body that oversees buses and underground trains in London.

Answer (score 0):

I would say *[mode of transport](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mode_of_transport)*.

Comment: [Wikipedia distinguishes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_of_transport) "mode of transport" and "means of transport" . Based on that I'm going for 'means'.

Answer (score 0):

**Vehicle** would also be a valid word for "mode of transportation". But **vehicle** can be understood as either the specific make and model, or the general class or type, so **type of vehicle** would be a clearer phrase.

If the list of possibilities  extends beyond vehicles possessed by the employees themselves, to include various forms of public transportation (electric trolley, electric train/light rail, fossil-fuel-powered bus, hydrogen bus), then **mode of transportation** would be the more generic choice.

In AmE, **transportation** is primarily associated with moving people and **transport** is primarily associated with moving goods.